# DataTables: (TypeError) m[v] is undefined

Tags: javascript, datatables

Trying to set up a DataTable with data provided as JSON by PHP.

```js
function request_data() {                    
    $.ajax({
        url: './inc/get_data.php?mode=1',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $("#frmMain").serialize(), // Serialize form data
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(baseData) {
            makeDataTable(baseData);
        }
});
}

function makeDataTable(new_data) {
    console.table(new_data);
    $('#table_log').DataTable({                        
        columns: [
            { data: 'id' },
            { data: 'zeitstempel' },
            { data: 'tag' },
            { data: 'message' },
            { data: 'file' }
        ],
        data: new_data
    });
}
```

The result from get_data.php in DevConsole looks like:

```bash
05:37:52.373 new_data
05:37:52.403
Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]​
0: Object { id: "3", zeitstempel: "2024-03-24 21:32:49.525789+01", tag: "#1", … }​
1: Object { id: "2", zeitstempel: "2024-03-24 19:50:17.568385+01", tag: "tag1", … }​
2: Object { id: "1", zeitstempel: "2024-03-24 19:49:44.23372+01", tag: "tag1", … }​
```

An empty DataTable is visible, and getting error:

```
TypeError: m[v] is undefined
```

Comment: Does this help: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/66037/uncaught-typeerror-n-v-is-undefined-when-trying-to-display-more-than-4-columns

Comment: Yes it helped. I had two colums defined in HTML. Empty <table> Tag is the working for dynamic DataTable creation

Answer (score 0):

I had two columns defined in `<thead>`, but defined 5 in the DataTable.

```html
<table id="table_log" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

An empty Tag solved the problem:

```
<table id="table_log" class="table">

</table>
```